# Problems with Java generics

Tags: java, generics

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list = (ArrayList<String>) Files.readAllLines(FilePath);
```

In the above code, if I remove the explicit casting in second line, the compiler gives an error. Why is this explicit cast required considering the fact that `Files.readAllLines(FilePath)` returns a `List<String>`, and `ArrayList<String>` implements `List<String>` ?

Comment: Use `List<String> list` instead.

Comment: `Files.readAllLines(FilePath)` returns a `List<String>`, but the implementation of the list might not be `ArrayList`. Your cast is therefore unsafe. You should just do `List<String> list = Files.readAllLines(filePath);`.

Comment: Also note, your cast should be in parentheses, like: list = (ArrayList<String>) Files.readAllLines(FilePath);

Comment: Every `ArrayList` is a `List`, but not every `List` is an `ArrayList`.

Comment: @cameron1024 Thanks for pointing out. I missed those while typing the code here though my original code was with parenthesis. Edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `Files.readAllLines()` only guarantees to return an object of type `List<String>`, but not of the more specific type `ArrayList<String>`. The actual implementation type of the returned list may vary between different JDK implementations (they just need to be sub-classes of `List<String>`, so while a cast to `ArrayList<String>` may work in your environment with your JDK implementation it may not work in another.

If you really need your list to be an ArrayList, you can use this code instead:

```java
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.addAll(Files.readAllLines(FilePath));
```

Answer (score 4):

As you've said, any `ArrayList<T>` is a `List<T>`. But the opposite is not true: a `List<T>` is not always an `ArrayList<T>`.

This means that if the method `readAllLines` is returning a `List<T>`, then you can assign the value to a `List<T>` variable, not any of its subtypes without an explicit downcast (which should always be avoided).

I don't even see why you would want to downcast it to `ArrayList<T>`, the less you imply about a type, freer you are.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you are doing a *downcasting*, i.e. you want to cast a parent class to a child class. This is very unsafe, since a child may offer more than a parent. In your example, an `ArrayList` has additional functionalities.
Thus, to ensure safety, the compiler will *never* allow an implicit downcasting (but *upcasting* is ok, as a child has necessarily all the functionalities of a parent).